# Upload the translation file from the template in WordPress (.mo and .po)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, po, mo

I want to put a function in the **functions.php** file so that when the user activates the template, all the files with **.mo** and **.po** extensions are copied to the `wp-content\languages\themes` path.

For this purpose I have used the following code which did not work:

```
function load_the_languages() {
 load_theme_textdomain( 'themePro', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_the_languages' );
```

The source I used to write the above function:

[load_theme_textdomain()](https://wp-kama.com/function/load_theme_textdomain)

Please help me to create a function that can copy all files with **.mo** and **.po** extension to `wp-content\languages\themes` path.

I came up with the above code after a lot of searching and I hope there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `load_theme_textdomain`() is used to load the translation files for the theme, but it doesn't actually copy the files to a different location. If you want to copy the .mo and .po files from your theme's `languages` directory to the `wp-content/languages/themes directory` when the theme is activated, you can use the `after_switch_theme` hook, which fires after the theme iss switched.

```
function copy_language_files_to_global_directory() {
    $source_directory = get_template_directory() . '/languages';
    $destination_directory = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/languages/themes';

    if (!is_dir($destination_directory)) {
        wp_mkdir_p($destination_directory);
    }

    // Copy .mo and .po files
    foreach (glob($source_directory . '/*.{mo,po}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
        $destination_file = $destination_directory . '/' . basename($file);
        if (!file_exists($destination_file)) {
            copy($file, $destination_file);
        }
    }
}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'copy_language_files_to_global_directory');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your time and the good code you wrote.

Comment: Hello. I created a new question regarding the same code you wrote. If possible, take a look at this question:[After placing the file in the path, copy it immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77450936/after-placing-the-file-in-the-path-copy-it-immediately)