# After placing the file in the path, copy it immediately

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I copy the desired file from the upload folder to the WordPress language folder using the following code:
(I know that only `.po and .mo` files should be in the language folder and this is just an example.)

```
function PDF_Files() {
    
    $upload = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_dir = $upload['basedir'];
    
  $uploadLanUser_directory= $upload_dir .'/test-for-pdf';
  $wordPress_directory = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/languages/themes';

  if ( !is_dir( $wordPress_directory ) ) {
    wp_mkdir_p( $wordPress_directory );
  }

  foreach ( glob( $uploadLanUser_directory . '/*.pdf', GLOB_BRACE ) as $file ) {
    $destination_file = $wordPress_directory . '/' . basename( $file );
    if ( !file_exists( $destination_file ) ) {
      copy( $file, $destination_file );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'PDF_Files' );
```

This code works correctly and copies my PDF file to the specified path after launching the template.

My problem is exactly here. I have to restart the template to copy the file.

Do you know how to edit the code so that when the PDF file is placed in the WordPress upload folder, the desired file is copied to the specified path immediately without having to restart the template?

Comment: For it to happen _immediately_, you would need some mechanism connected to the file system, that allows you to trigger a script when a directory content changes. The more practical solution would be to trigger the above code that reads & copies the files in a regular interval via a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your function PDF_Files is hooked to the after_switch_theme action, which is why it only runs when the theme is activated or switched. To automatically copy the PDF files upon their upload, you'll need to hook into an action that fires during the upload process.

WordPress provides the add_attachment action, which is triggered when an attachment (like a PDF) is uploaded. By hooking your function to this action, you can automate the copying process. Here’s how you can modify your function:

Change the Hook: Use the add_attachment action to trigger your function when a new file is uploaded.
Check File Type: Since this will trigger for all uploads, you should check if the uploaded file is a PDF before proceeding.
Here’s an updated version of your function:

```
function auto_copy_pdf_files( $post_ID ) {
    if ( wp_attachment_is( 'pdf', $post_ID ) ) {
        $upload = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_dir = $upload['basedir'];

        $uploadLanUser_directory = $upload_dir . '/test-for-pdf';
        $wordPress_directory = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/languages/themes';

        if ( !is_dir( $wordPress_directory ) ) {
            wp_mkdir_p( $wordPress_directory );
        }

        $file = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            $destination_file = $wordPress_directory . '/' . basename( $file );
            if ( !file_exists( $destination_file ) ) {
                copy( $file, $destination_file );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'auto_copy_pdf_files' );
```

**Here's what's happening:**

The function auto_copy_pdf_files is triggered when a file is uploaded.
It first checks if the uploaded file is a PDF.
If it is, it proceeds to copy the file to the desired directory, just like your original function.
With this modification, your PDFs should be automatically copied over when they're uploaded, eliminating the need to restart the theme. This should make your workflow smoother and more efficient!

Comment: I apologize for my late reply. I checked your answer and it worked very well. Thanks for the advice and the very good code you wrote.